# Select Hierarchize/drilldown columns from Analysis service

Tags: sql, mdx

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[ContractValue]
   ,[Measures].[ContractVolumeMWh]
   ,[Measures].[ContractVolumeMW]
  }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
   ,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Hierarchize
    (
      DrillDownMember
      (
        DrillDownMember
        (
          DrillDownMember
          (
            DrillDownMember
            (
              CrossJoin
              (
                {
                  [HalfHourEnding].[Year].[All]
                 ,[HalfHourEnding].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS
                }
               ,{
                  (
                    [HalfHourEnding].[Quarter].[All]
                   ,[HalfHourEnding].[Month].[All]
                   ,[Book].[Book].[All]
                   ,[InstrumentType].[InstrumentType].[All]
                  )
                }
              )
             ,[HalfHourEnding].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS AS year
             ,[HalfHourEnding].[Quarter]
            )
           ,[HalfHourEnding].[Quarter].[Quarter].ALLMEMBERS
           ,[HalfHourEnding].[Month]
          )
         ,[HalfHourEnding].[Month].[Month].ALLMEMBERS
         ,[Book].[Book]
        )
       ,[Book].[Book].[Book].ALLMEMBERS
       ,[InstrumentType].[InstrumentType]
      )
    )
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
   ,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM [ContractDetail]
WHERE 
  (
    [AsAt].[As at Business Date].&[2016-06-04T00:00:00]
   ,[Region].[Region].&[TTT]
  )
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,FORMAT_STRING
 ,LANGUAGE
 ,BACK_COLOR
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,FONT_FLAGS;
```

Which when I run in Microsoft Analysis Server I get:

[image]

Which is the right output, however I am not getting the header’s for the five first columns. This creates the problem because when I want to select this data from tsql using openquery I am not able to select any of these columns.

This is the query from tsql, it gives me everything in the right order but I am not  able to get year quarter month book instrumentType.

```
DECLARE @ContractsTable as TABLE ( 
                                                                                                         Year   varchar(100),
                                                                                                         Quarter   varchar(100),  
                Month  varchar(100),
                                                                                                         Book  varchar(100),      
             InstrumentType      varchar(100), 
                                                              Value                      decimal(16,2),
                                                                                                         Volume_MWH         decimal(16,2),  
                                                                                                         Volume_MW                decimal(16,2) 


                                                       )


Declare @ContractsQuery as nvarchar(max)
SET @ContractsQuery =       
'
SELECT 
"[Measures].[ContractValue]" as value, 
"[Measures].[ContractVolumeMWh]" as MWH,
"[Measures].[ContractVolumeMW]" as MW
from OpenQuery(CONTRACT_IMDB,     
   ''SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[ContractValue]
   ,[Measures].[ContractVolumeMWh]
   ,[Measures].[ContractVolumeMW]
  }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
   ,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Hierarchize
    (
      DrillDownMember
      (
        DrillDownMember
        (
          DrillDownMember
          (
            DrillDownMember
            (
              CrossJoin
              (
                {
                  [HalfHourEnding].[Year].[All]
                 ,[HalfHourEnding].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS
                }
               ,{
                  (
                    [HalfHourEnding].[Quarter].[All]
                   ,[HalfHourEnding].[Month].[All]
                   ,[Book].[Book].[All]
                   ,[InstrumentType].[InstrumentType].[All]
                  )
                }
              )
             ,[HalfHourEnding].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS AS year
             ,[HalfHourEnding].[Quarter]
            )
           ,[HalfHourEnding].[Quarter].[Quarter].ALLMEMBERS
           ,[HalfHourEnding].[Month]
          )
         ,[HalfHourEnding].[Month].[Month].ALLMEMBERS
         ,[Book].[Book]
        )
       ,[Book].[Book].[Book].ALLMEMBERS
       ,[InstrumentType].[InstrumentType]
      )
    )
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
   ,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM [ContractDetail]
WHERE 
  (
    [AsAt].[As at Business Date].&[2016-06-04T00:00:00]
   ,[Region].[Region].&[TTT]
  )
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,FORMAT_STRING
 ,LANGUAGE
 ,BACK_COLOR
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,FONT_FLAGS; ''

)
' 


INSERT INTO @ContractsTable(Value,Volume_MWH,Volume_MW) 
EXEC sp_executesql @ContractsQuery 

Select * From @ContractsTable
```

The output is

[image]

Now I simply just want to extract the output from analysis services, but I am not able to select all the columns. And I am not able to figure out how I define these columns where I am drilling down in the dimensions.

Comment: initially just replace you current Select clause with Select * .... you will then know what the columns names are - usually when using openquery you get more columns returned than is specified in the mdx. From the output of Select * you can see the column headers

Answer (score 0):

You can use microsofts `OPENQUERY` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(olap_server,
     'SELECT [unit sales] FROM myCubeName')
```

where `olap_server` is the name of the linked olap server

or

you can use the execute olap function that is available here:
https://olapextensions.codeplex.com/

Initially we used `openquery` but we now use `olapextensions` as it seems simpler and more efficient.

---

**Edit**

Initially run the following to find the headers of all the columns available:

```
Declare @ContractsQuery as nvarchar(max)
SET @ContractsQuery =       
'
SELECT 
*
from OpenQuery(CONTRACT_IMDB,     
   ''SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[ContractValue]
   ,[Measures].[ContractVolumeMWh]
   ,[Measures].[ContractVolumeMW]
  }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
   ,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Hierarchize
    (
      DrillDownMember
      (
        DrillDownMember
        (
          DrillDownMem
...
...
```

Then replace the * with specific names.

Comment: If you read my code that is what I have done: SELECT 
"[Measures].[ContractValue]" as value, 
"[Measures].[ContractVolumeMWh]" as MWH,
"[Measures].[ContractVolumeMW]" as MW
from OpenQuery(CONTRACT_IMDB, however.. now I am not able to select the columns holding year, quarter, month, hedgebook etc

Comment: @ALEXANDER if those columns are returned by the mdx then they can be selected in the sql! Just do `Select *` first so you know the names of the columns - then add the column names into your sql.....or am I missing something.